# PHP Copy a document in MongoDB, replacing it's MongoID

Tags: php, mongodb

When changing a certain document where (it's unsure how exactly the structure is), I want to create a backup of this document in another collection before saving it back to my current collection. To do the backup, I tried this:

```
$mongoDbObj = $collection->findOne($filter);
...
$collectionBackup->insert($mongoDbObj,true);
```

... but this works only once because the MongoID is copied. When I try to backup the same document again, the MongoID already exists in the backupCollection. So my question is:

Can I copy a MongoDB document in PHP, overwriting the MongoID with a new MongoID, before inserting into another collection, without changing the MongoID of the original document?

---

**This question simplified is**: How can I do this:

```
$mongoDbObj = $collection->findOne($filter);
...
$collectionBackup->insert($mongoDbObj,true);
// change MongoId so the next line doesn't throw exception
$collectionBackup->insert($mongoDbObj,true);
// save my object back with the original MongoID
$collection->save($mongoDbObj);
```

Also helpful would be how to clone / copy a MongoDB document, then it would be easy to get around the problem by just sticking a new MongoID in a copied document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mongoDbObj = $collection->findOne($filter);
$mongoDbObjBak = array();

foreach($mongoDbObj as $key => $value) {
    if($key != '_id') {
        $mongoDbObjBak[$key] = $value;
    }
}

$collectionBackup->insert($mongoDbObjBak,true);
$collection->save($mongoDbObj);
```

Comment: Good point: A MongoDB document is just a PHP array, so you can treat it like such. Thanks! And by the way: Tobias, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to **copy a document** and duplicate it in an other collection **without _id** mongo .

Use fields query in order to **remove fields** you don't need.

Example :

```
$mongoDbObj = $collection->findOne($filter);
$mongoDbObj->fields(array("_id" => false));
```

Docs : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.fields.php

Have fun :)